# javascript overwrite previous element added to array

Tags: javascript

When i push into my array, it overwrite the last element added.

Here is my code:

```
const array = [{ name: [] }];

const test = `result1
result2
result3`;
const ways = test.split(/[\n\r]+/).map(aaa => (aaa));

array.forEach((obj) => {
  ways.forEach((element) => {
    obj.item = [{ result: element }];
  });
});
```

The output i get :

```
[ 
  { 
    "name": [], 
    "item": [{ "result": "result3" }] 
  }
]
```

The output i want :

```
[
  {
    "name": [],
    "item": [
      { "result": "result1" },
      { "result": "result2" },
      { "result": "result3" }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: just define `obj.item` as array and push values to it

Comment: You aren't pushing anything into an array.

Comment: Some sidenotes: what is the `map` for? You take each value of the array that `split` creates and replace it with itself.
And why would you want to iterate over the `ways`-array? You basically have an array that you want to store, as an array, in another variable. So you iterate over it and copy each value by hand. I assume you want to create a deep copy of the `ways`-array; I'd recommend using some built-in solution like `Array.from(ways)` to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare obj.item as an array and instead of equating values you should push them in the array

```js
const array = [{
  name: []
}];

const test = `result1
result2
result3`;
const ways = test.split(/[\n\r]+/).map(aaa => (aaa));

array.forEach((obj) => {
  obj.item = [];
  ways.forEach((element) => {
    obj.item.push({
      result: element
    });
  });
});
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const array = [{ name: [] }];

const test = `result1
result2
result3`;
const ways = test.split(/[\n\r]+/).map(aaa => (aaa));

array.map((obj) => {
obj.item = [];
  ways.map((element) => {
    obj.item .push([{ result: element }]);
  });
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **reduce** method

```js
const test = `result1
result2
result3`;

const res = test.split(/[\n\r]+/).map(aaa => (aaa)).reduce((all, acc) => {
  const [a] = all
  a.item.push({
    "result": acc
  })
  return all
}, [{
  name: [],
  item: []
}])

console.log(res)
```